# MSBuild, properties and imported files

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to run an msbuild task that populates a property or Item from an imported file "A" and then use these values in another file which imports file "A"?

EDIT: FileX imports FileA and FileY imports FileA. One of FileA's property is changed in FileX. Can this changed value be accessed in FileY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry its a bit confusing:

Are you saying FileX imports FileA and FileY imports FileA. FileX sets property P in FileX but FileY reads it? If there is no relationship between X & Y then the only way to do it would be use the fact that properties in MSBUILD overlap with evironment vars. So possbly calling

```
<exec ... setx.exe Propertyname SomeValue.... /> in fileA and the $(Propertyname) in FileB
```

Comment: FileX imports FileA and FileY imports FileA. One of FileA's property is changed in FileX. Can this changed value be accessed in FileY?

Comment: everything is done in the msbuild execution context. So assuming X & Y are imported in the same context then yes the latter will pick up changes from the first as at the time of import the second will already have a value set and thus the original value in fileA will not be used.